# Extra white space in IE scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable div in IE9. There's an extra white space at the right side of the scrollbar.

[image]

When I move the scroll to the right, the white space at the right side gets smaller but transfers on the left side of the scroller until it completely disappears.

[image]

Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJW2L/) where you can see the white space in the scrollbar.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: provide link in website

Comment: can't. it's internal. plus it's only a div that has the style rules:

{
 display:inline-block;
 overflow-x:auto;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 white-space:nowrap;
 width:1000px
}

Comment: jsfiddle example pls.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by white space rendering between inline-block elements. It immediately reminded me of Chris Coyier's [article on the subject at CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/):

> This isn't a "bug" (I don't think). It's just the way setting elements on a line works. You want spaces between words that you type to be spaces right? The spaces between these blocks are just like spaces between words. That's not to say the spec couldn't be updated to say that spaces between inline-block elements should be nothing, but I'm fairly certain that is a huge can of worms that is unlikely to ever happen.

He offers a number of solutions.

Comment: but the scrollbar doesn't affect the other elements beside it. The scrollbar is on the element itself, not a container

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue running IE10 in IE9 mode. Can you confirm that this is happening for others?

Comment: yup, it doesn't happen in IE10 IE9 mode, just plain ol' IE9